# How to find the sides of a polygon in an image?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a list of connected pixels (tuples of x and y coordinates) forming the outer boundaries of a polygon in an image.  How can I pick out its sides suppose they are all straight?  What should I do if the lines are not too straight, and contain deviations?  Is there anything readily made in Python Image Library or Numpy for such a task?  Thanks!

Comment: please use websearch for questions like this

Comment: @Piglet, I did but found no satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use OpenCVs [approxPolyDP](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp)

You can reduce the number of vertices using that function.

> The functions approxPolyDP approximate a curve or a polygon with
> another curve/polygon with less vertices so that the distance between
> them is less or equal to the specified precision. It uses the
> Douglas-Peucker algorithm
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_algorithm

Comment: Thank you for the pointer.  I am restricted to using PIL and numpy in my solution.